# Is there a way to return a list of objects from a MySQL stored procedure to JPA?

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpa-2.0

The procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `hw1_db_1`.`r2_browse_movies_by_title`(IN str_title VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM `hw1_db_1`.`movies` WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', str_title, '%');
END
```

called in a `Stateless` EJB:

```java
public List<Movie> searchTitles(String query) {
    StoredProcedureQuery nq = em
        .createStoredProcedureQuery("r2_browse_movies_by_title");
    nq.registerStoredProcedureParameter("str_title", String.class,
        ParameterMode.IN);
    return nq.setParameter("str_title", query).getResultList(); // unchecked cast
}
```

Unfortunately it does not return a `List<Movie>` but a `List<Object[]>` with the movie attributes. Any way to return a `List<Movie>` ? Any programmatic way to convert ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume

```
    EntityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery(String procedureName, Class... resultClasses)
Create an instance of StoredProcedureQuery for executing a stored procedure in the database.
```

Just try passing the resultClasses to you entities.

> The resultClass arguments must be specified in the order in which the
>   result sets will be returned by the stored procedure invocation.
>
> Parameters:
>       procedureName - name of the stored procedure in the database
>       resultClasses - classes to which the result sets produced by the stored procedure are to be mapped

Comment: Yes that did it - I was looking to parametrize the `getResultList()` but that accepted no parameters